# How to use a Matplotlib proxy artist with stackplot?

Tags: matplotlib

Example (runs in `ipython --pylab`):

```
x = arange(25)
Y = maximum(0,2+randn(7,25))
stackplot(x,Y)
legend(('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'))
```

**The problem:** instead of a proper legend, I get an empty rectangle. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1943) and one work-around is using another plot element that supports legend, also called a *[proxy artist](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist)*. Now I wonder how this idiom is translated to my case with seven data series. Here is what I tried:

```
 proxy = [Rectangle((0,0), 0,0) for _ in Y]
 legend(proxy, ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'))
```

Now I have a legend with 7 elements, but they are all blue. How can I have the proxy artists match the stackplot colors?

Comment: Note to self: using `--pylab` or `%pylab` [is discouraged](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html). Better import numpy/matplotlib explicitely and use an unpolluted namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the color from the `PolyCollections` which form the stackplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.arange(25)
Y = np.maximum(0,2+np.random.randn(7,25))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sp = ax.stackplot(x,Y)

proxy = [mpl.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 0,0, facecolor=pol.get_facecolor()[0]) for pol in sp]

ax.legend(proxy, ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'))
```

[image]